# broadcast receiver not invoking

Tags: android

I am Doing An application which is basically a reminder app.It will save all the details such as date,Time,recipient number,Content Text etc in the database and after that it will send an sms using this detail on this stored date and time

Actually I am not using any calender Instance
What I am planning to do is, Set a broadcast receiver which invoke every day and then search in
database ,If the date found it will send an sms using that date and time

Now thing i want to do is create a broadcast receiver which calls everday

The code I used id

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Broadcast receiver Started");
     Intent dailyUpdater = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(dailyUpdater);
        Log.d("AlarmReceiver", "Called context.startService from AlarmReceiver.onReceive");
```

also registered in the manifest with action Time_changed

But the receiver is not calling can anybody help me to sort outthis problem

Comment: Is your class a childclass of 'extends BroadcastReceiver'?

Comment: are you adding action on your broadcastreceiver and are you registering it?

Comment: Show us where you registered with `AlarmManager`.

Comment: ofcours it extend broadcast receiver,

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast receiver is a background process. This may help you..

```
Intent dailyUpdater = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
dailyUpdater.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startService(dailyUpdater);
```